# Gulp uglify doesn't work

Tags: javascript, ubuntu, gulp, gulp-uglify

I try to systematize some development works on my project. For this goal I use gulp, and one of stubborn module: gulp-uglify. I have short script:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    gp_concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    gp_rename = require('gulp-rename'),
    gp_uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

gulp.task('source', function () {
    gulp.src(['source/src/module.js', 'source/src/**/*.js'])
        .pipe(gp_concat('angular-deck.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('source/dist/'))
        .pipe(gp_rename('angular-deck.min.js'))
        .pipe(gp_uglify().on('error', function(e) { console.log('\x07',e.message); return this.end(); }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('source/dist/'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch('source/src/**/*.js', ['source']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['source', 'watch']);
```

But this module is often breaks. Log:

```
old@old:~/Desktop/PROJECTS/angular-deck$ gulp
[22:03:44] Using gulpfile ~/Desktop/PROJECTS/angular-deck/gulpfile.js
[22:03:44] Starting 'source'...
[22:03:44] Finished 'source' after 13 ms
[22:03:44] Starting 'watch'...
[22:03:44] Finished 'watch' after 11 ms
[22:03:44] Starting 'default'...
[22:03:44] Finished 'default' after 10 μs
 Unexpected token name «type», expected punc «,»
[22:03:58] Starting 'source'...
[22:03:58] Finished 'source' after 2.78 ms
 Unexpected token name «type», expected punc «,»
[22:04:02] Starting 'source'...
[22:04:02] Finished 'source' after 2.35 ms
 Unexpected token name «type», expected punc «,»
```

I look for the answer of this problem in issues in github repository, but decision didn't find.

P.S >>> angular-deck.js is created normal.

P.S.S. >>> I think it's not important, but I work on lubuntu 14.04.

Comment: This doesn't seems to be a problem with *gulp* or *uglify*, but most likely with one of your scripts that has a syntax error

Comment: WAT? Error in code 0_o... moment, check it

Comment: Yes, it is. Question can be closed.

Comment: Okay, closing it for a simple typo error, this may takes some little time